# How can I install both Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 beta in my Mac

Tags: xcode5, xcode6

I want to start developing apps in Swift programming language in Xcode 6 beta. But I need to keep my Xcode 5 to continue my development in Objective C. I don't want to use Xcode 6 beta for my current development since it is still in beta. Any one can hep me to do that

Comment: Just install it. It's a separate app.

Comment: Just install it. The beta is named Xcode6-Beta, it won't overwrite your Xcode 5 version. You can distinguish them easily as well, the beta has a red label over its icon.

Comment: Thanks for the details, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html

Xcode 6 Beta can coexist on a Mac computer with previous versions of Xcode.

This prerelease version of Xcode is distributed as a single application bundle available from developer.apple.com to authorized seed developers in a disk image file (DMG). To install during the beta period, open the downloaded DMG file and drag the Xcode icon to your Applications folder. Upon final release, Xcode is installed through the Mac App Store.